# Combination of a list of lists so that each combination has unique elements

Tags: c#, list, combinations

Ok so, I have a list of lists, like the title says and I want to make combinations of k lists in which every list has different elements than the rest.

**Example**:

I have the following list of lists:

```
{ {1,2,3} , {1,11} , {2,3,6} , {6,5,7} , {4,8,9} }
```

A valid 3-sized combination of these lists could be:

```
{ {1,11}, {4,8,9} ,{6,5,7} }
```

This is only ONE of the valid combinations, what I want to return is a list of all the valid combinations of K lists.

An invalid combination would be:

```
{ {1,11} ,{2, 3, 6}, {6, 5, 7} }
```

because the element 6 is present in the second and third list.

I already have a code that does this but it just finds all possible combinations and checks if they are valid before addding it to a final result list. As this list of lists is quite large (153 lists) when K gets bigger, the time taken is ridiculously big too (at K = 5 it takes me about 10 minutes.)

I want to see if there's an efficient way of doing this.
Below is my current code (the lists I want to combine are attribute of the class Item):

```
public void recursiveComb(List<Item> arr, int len,  int startPosition, Item[] result)
{
    if (len == 0)
    {            
        if (valid(result.ToList()))
        {                
          //Here I add the result to final list

          //valid is just a function that checks if any list has repeated elements in other  
        }            
        return;
    }

    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.Count - len; i++)
    {       
        result[result.Length - len] = arr[i];
        recursiveComb(arr, len - 1,  i + 1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question... Yes i can see whats valid and whats not, however what do you want to do with this. Filter or validate?

Comment: I want to filter all the valid combinations and add them to a final list.

Comment: Do you care which inner lists will be removed?

Comment: i mean why did you keep `{1,11}` and not  `{1,2,3}`, actually wow im confused. you need to add more information

Comment: @TheGeneral he wanted to show the invalid example in relation to the valid one. its just ONE possibility of lists out of the many he wants to gather in a list and output to the user at the end. interesting question indeed.

Comment: Ahh yes i see now

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx
to keep track of distinct elements as you build the output from the candidates in the input list of lists/tuples

accumulate an output list of non overlapping tuples by Iterating across the input list of tuples and evaluate each tuple as a candidate as follows:
For  each input tuple, insert each tuple element into the HashSet. If the element you are trying to insert is already in the set, then the tuple fails the constraint and should be skipped, otherwise the tuple elements are all distinct from ones already in the output.

The hashset object effectively maintains a registry of distinct items in your accepted list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your code correctly then, you are passing each `list<int>` from your input to `recursiveComb()` function. which look like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputnestedList.Count; i++)
{
    recursiveComb();
   // Inside of recursiveComb() you are using one more for loop with recursion.
   // This I observed from your first parameter i.e. List<int>
}
```

**Correct me if I am wrong**

This leads to time complexity **more than O(n^2)**

---

Here is my simplest solution, with two forloops without recursion.

```
List<List<int>> x = new List<List<int>>{ new List<int>(){1,2,3} , new List<int>(){1,11} , new List<int>(){2,3,6} , new List<int>(){6,5,7} , new List<int>(){4,8,9} };
List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < x.Count;i++)
{
    int temp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < x.Count; j++)
    {
        if (i != j && x[i].Intersect(x[j]).Any())
            temp++;
    }

    // This condition decides, that elements of  ith list are available in other lists
    if (temp <= 1)
        result.Add(x[i]);
}
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs);
```

Now when I print execution time then output is

```
Execution Time: 11.4628
```

Check execution time of your code. If execution time of your code is higher than mine, then you can consider it as efficient code

Proof of code: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SJhGQ)

Happy coding

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The problem is I want to make more than one k-sized combination. And add it to a List of combinations. I want to consider ALL possible AND valid combinations and add them to a list of combinations. So for example in my original post, the output should be a list of all the valid combinations like the one I gave.

Comment: Have you checked my implementation from dotnet fiddler, here https://dotnetfiddle.net/7SJhGQ This solution returns your expected output

Comment: Yes, I did, the problem is: that is only ONE of the combinations possible, I want to get all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then this will work:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Get Unique List sets
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sets"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<List<T>> GetUniqueSets<T>(List<List<T>> sets )
        {
            List<List<T>> cache = new List<List<T>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < sets.Count; i++)
            {
                // add to cache if it's empty
                if (cache.Count == 0)
                {
                    cache.Add(sets[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    //check whether current item is in the cache and also whether current item intersects with any of the items in cache
                    var cacheItems = from item in cache where (item != sets[i] && item.Intersect(sets[i]).Count() == 0) select item;

                    //if not add to cache
                    if (cacheItems.Count() == cache.Count)
                    {
                        cache.Add(sets[i]);
                    }

                }
            }


            return cache;

        }
```

Tested, it's fast and took 00:00:00.0186033 for finding sets.